# CircleCI - pytest cannot find files used by tests

Tags: python, pytest, circleci, tox

I'm using tox to run tests in my CircleCI deployment. I have a directory called `tests`, and within this directory I have another directory called `test_files` with files I use for mocking, e.g., files with JSON data. Locally I run the tests successfully with the mock files, but in CircleCI, pytest cannot find the JSON files within the directory: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test_files/data.json'`

This is my `tox.ini`:

```
[tox]
envlist = py37,py38,flake8

[testenv]
deps=-r{toxinidir}/requirements.txt
     -r{toxinidir}/test-requirements.txt

commands=
   pytest -v tests
```

and my `config.yml`:

```
version: 2
jobs:
  # using tox
  toxify:

      docker:
        - image: python:3.8

      steps:
        - checkout
        - run:
            name: tox build
            command: |
              pip install tox
              tox -q
        - run:
            name: deploy
            command: |
              ./deploy.sh
workflows:
  version: 2
  build_and_release:
    jobs:
      - toxify:
          filters:
            tags:
              only: /^v\d+\.\d+\.\d+$/
```

Test example:

```
from my_package.image import ImageValidator

def test_valid_image():
    image_validator = ImageValidator("test_files/default_image.png")
    assert image_validator.is_valid_image() is True
```

I open the image with:

```
file_path = glob.glob(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(file_path), '*.png'))[0]
with open(file_path, "rb") as image:
    image_data = image.read()
    ...
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Please show your test code and the full traceback.

Comment: If you are using a path like `test_files/data.json` in the code, your tests can only be executed from the tests directory. In your CI job however, you are running `pytest` from the repo root. Either fix the tests to build paths relative to caller module file, or run the tests from the correct directory.

Comment: I added an example, @hoefling the files are in my tests directory which I'm running with pytest as seen in the tox.ini.

Comment: The files may be in your tests directory, but you are not in tests directory when running the tests - either change to `ImageValidator(os.path.join(__file__, '..', '..', 'test_files', 'default_image.png'))` (or whatever the image path is relative to calling module), or to `ImageValidator("tests/test_files/default_image.png")` or change the working directory when running tests (smth like `cd tests && pytest -v; cd ..`). First one is workdir-agnostic, the latter two are bound to workdir.

Comment: @hoefling I made the workdir relative and it worked. You can add it as answer and I'll mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Restating the comments: if you use relative paths in your code:

```
def test_valid_image():
    image_validator = ImageValidator("test_files/default_image.png")
```

the path `test_files/default_image.png` will be resolved relative to the current working directory, so if the full path is e.g.

```
/root/tests/test_files/default_image.png
```

the file will be found only if you run the test from `/root/tests`: `cd /root/tests; pytest` will work, while every other workdir, e.g. `cd /root; pytest tests/` will fail. This is what currently happens in your `tox` config:

```
commands=
   pytest -v tests
```

starts `pytest` in project root, looking for tests in `tests` directory, so `test_files/default_image.png` resolves to `project root/test_files/default_image.png` and not `project root/tests/test_files/default_image.png` as you would expect.

There are many ways to circumvent this. Best is to resolve the paths relative to some static file, e.g. the calling module:

```
def test_valid_image():
    path = os.path.join(__file__, '..', '..', 'test_files', 'default_image.png')
    image_validator = ImageValidator(path)
```

or, by knowing that `pytest` stores project root in its configuration:

```
def test_valid_image(request):
    rootdir = request.config.rootdir
    path = os.path.join(rootdir, 'tests', 'test_files', 'default_image.png')
    image_validator = ImageValidator(path)
```

Now the path will be resolved ignoring the working directory and tied to a file that has always the same path; running `pytest tests/` or `cd tests/; pytest` has now the same effect.

Other ways are playing with changing the working directory. Since your test expect to be executed from `tests` dir, navigate to it in the `tox.ini`:

```
commands=
    cd tests && pytest; cd ..
```

or

```
commands=
    pushd tests; pytest; popd
```

etc.